# Is it possible to check the username of the database (MySQL), if correct without having to write correct password in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I want to check if the username of mysql database is correct in a local environment, without having to write the correct database password, is it possible?

Something like this:

```
$db = new Database('localhost', 'root', 'anything');
$db->conn();
$db->serverAvailable(); # returns true
$db->usernameExists(); # returns true
$db->isConnected(); # returns false
```

Comment: try to connect and see what error you got from mysql

Comment: The error message  is the same as writting wrong database password with wrong username.

Comment: You cant without trying to connecting to mysql, try to connect, if connection success, then its true if not success then its false

Comment: well if connection is success then the username and password are both correct but if fail the username might still be correct but the password isn't or the otherwise.

Comment: No, the error message will not tell you if the username is correct. It will give "Access denied" if it can't match the full username/password combination.